# I am working on a Layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

I am new to Android and I am designing a layout using `LinearLayout` where I want all the three `buttons` to take equal spaces on the `LinearLayout`.
I did it by giving them equal `width` but then they do not cover the whole length. Is there a simpler approach to it?

Comment: Can you share the xml that you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Android Dev. I am sure this might be a duplicated question and would advise you to search through previous answers before putting a new one.

But let me tell you how you can achieve this is a simple application of `weight` in layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:weightSum="3">
        
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Button 3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        
        
        
    </LinearLayout>
    

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see above the `weightSum` tells the Linear layout the total weight of items in the layout below

`android:layout_weight="1"` is a weightage of each element in the layout. So there are three buttons and each have a weight of 1, which adds to 3 of the Linear Layout. So each button will be allocated the same space. You can play with weights to give different spaces to different views inside the Linear layout. You can leave the weightSum attribute and the linear layout can calculate on its own too based on the children's sum of the weights.

So you see this is a kind of relative spacing given to the Views based on the weights they carry. Hoping this was helpful to you and what you were expecting to know.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Primoz,it is better to have `android:layout_width = "0dp"` so that your team or other persons can better understand the width controlling View.

Comment: Hello,thank you . This solved it for me. Thank you so much, I thought there should be a simpler way

Comment: If you think this was helpful enough for your requirement then you can accept the answer.

Comment: There is no need to specify `weightSum` on `LinearLayout` for such case. It is usually better if you don't, since it complicates code maintenance.

Also, if you set `layout_weight` of element to `0dp`, you tell the next person reading your code, that it is not this view, which controls the width, but it's parent.

Comment: Thank you for adding to the answer. I think I  mentioned that weightSum is optional. But adding the 0dp is useful tip as well. I might have rushed over it while focusing only on the  ```weight``` attribute. I will add this as an edit. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say anything without code sample, but most likely you are missing `layout_weight` attribute.

Here's an example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 3" />
</LinearLayout>
```